# how can i access the value of each data from this json?

Tags: json, node.js

```
{
    "sachin.company": {
        "classkey": "dotcompany",
        "status": "available"
    },
    "sachin.com": {
        "classkey": "domcno",
        "status": "regthroughothers"
    },
    "sachin.co.in": {
        "classkey": "thirdleveldotin",
        "status": "regthroughothers"
    },
   "sachin.org": {
        "classkey": "domorg",
        "status": "regthroughothers"
    },
    "sachin.guru": {
        "classkey": "dotguru",
        "status": "available"
    },
    "sachin.sexy": {
        "classkey": "dotsexy",
        "status": "available"
    },
    "sachin.nettlds=asia": {
        "status": "unknown"
    }
}
```

I want to access the classKey and status from this object.
how can I access for each of keys value?
I tried this `var keys = Object.keys(response);` but this only create the array like `["sachin.company", "sachin.in", "sachin.community", "sachin.com", "sachin.computer", "sachin.co.in", "sachin.org", "sachin.compare", "sachin.net"]`

Comment: What do you mean by access each of the key values? Do you want an array of all classkeys and a separate array of all statuses?

Comment: yes, I want to access status and class key for every domain name.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(parsedJson).forEach(function(value){
    var classKey = parsedJson[value].classKey;
    var status = parsedJson[value].status;
    //do whatever you want with them
});
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't get can you please explain.

Comment: @sachinyadav Parse your JSON file and put the results into a variable called parsedJson. Then run this code and put what you want to do with the data in the forEach loop.

Comment: which question?

Comment: @sachinyadav oops answer* sorry

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to get all defined values**

do as follows,

```
var allValues = [];
var keys = Object.keys(parsedJson);
Object.values(parsedJson).forEach(function(x) {
    Object.values(x).forEach(function(y){
       this.allValues.push(y);
    }, this);
}, this);
```

`allValues` will give you what you want. 
Thanks.